# jQuery dynamic search results from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-events

I have a created dynamic search that takes data from an input form and searches through an array of objects for matches. These matches (if they exist) are displayed on one line of a result along with a 'button' to click to take action on that specific search result line.

Each object in the array corresponds to a line of the result assuming that the search term if found in that object.

I have created a delegated listener to listen for clicks on the button for each shown result line. How do I get the button to act on the the 'index: number' contained in the object that created that line of the results.

My code so far is an follows:

```
var multiArr = [
{label: "Asap Rocky", song: "National", index: 0},
{label: "Rihanna", song: "Umbrella", index: 1},
{label: "Coldplay", song: "Paradise", index: 2}];



$('#results').on("click", ".result-button", function(event) {
    alert("You clicked:" + event.target.nodeName);
    console.dir($(this).text);
});




$("#finder").keyup(function(e){
        var q = $("#finder").val();
        console.log("Search Bar contents: " + q);

        var pattern = new RegExp( "^" + q, "i");

        $("#results").empty();

        for (var i = 0; i < multiArr.length; i++){

            console.log("Checking for " + q + " in " + multiArr[i].label);
            console.log("The above is " + pattern.test(multiArr[i].label));

            if (pattern.test(multiArr[i].label)) {
                console.log("something in here beings with " + q);

                /*console.log("Img Url: " + thaArr);*/
                //do something
                $("#results").append("<div class='result-line'><div class='result-img'><img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/36wDeLKKoXE/default.jpg' class='center-result-img'></div><div class='result-song-info'><div class='result-song-title'><p>" + multiArr[i].song + "</p></div><div class='result-song-artist'><p>" + multiArr[i].label + "</p></div></div><div class='result-button'>>></div></div>");
            } 

        }
    });
```

Comment: just add a data-index attribute to your button with the index of i that matched in the multiArr and then retrieve it in your listener

Comment: I think the way I'd do it would be to add a div with id equal to the index # for each result. Then add click listeners on each div.

Comment: I did end up coming to the conclusion that I should add a div containing as you mentioned, that index-value. But I had done it in a less elegant fashion. As plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to first attach a data attribute to the result-button itself and then fetch that data on your click callback, where the data you are attaching is the index value of your element.

In order words, you would add to the result-button div where you append to #results, that is, this:

```
"<div class='result-button'>"
```

the following data attribute:

```
"<div class='result-button' data-id='" + multiArr[i].index + "'>"
```

Then, in your click call back, you can simply get that id by using this:

```
$(this).data("id")
```

Now, just in case this doesn't make total since, I decided to help you out a little bit more by improving your code some.  The main improvement I made is that my example doesn't re-create the html on each filter change.  Instead, all of the data is appended to the page at the start, and then it is either hidden or shown depending on the label text. Additionally, I changed the way you are building up the elements to make it easier to edit in the future.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/seibert_cody/j4rqdh8L/

HTML:

```
<input id="finder" type="text">
<div id="results"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    // Set up the test data
    var multiArr = [
        {
            label: "Asap Rocky", 
            song: "National", 
            index: 0
        },
        {
            label: "Rihanna", 
            song: "Umbrella", 
            index: 1
        },
        {
            label: "Coldplay", 
            song: "Paradise", 
            index: 2
        }
    ]; 

    // Append it all to the #results page initially
    for (var i = 0; i < multiArr.length; i++){  
        $("#results").append(
            $("<div class='result-line'></div>").append(
                $("<div class='result-img'></div>").append(
                    $("<img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/36wDeLKKoXE/default.jpg' class='center-result-img'>")
                ).append(
                    $("<div class='result-song-info'></div>").append(
                        $("<div class='result-song-title'></div>").append(
                            $("<p>" + multiArr[i].song + "</p>")
                        )
                    )
                ).append(
                    $("<div class='result-song-artist'></div>").append(
                        $("<p>" + multiArr[i].label + "</p>")
                    )
                ).append(
                    $("<div class='result-button' data-id='" + multiArr[i].index + "'>Play</div>")
                )
            )
        );      
    }

    // Clicked on the play button
    $('#results').on("click", ".result-button", function(event){
        console.log($(this).data("id"));
    }); 


    // Only show the labels matching filter
    $("#finder").keyup(function(e){
        var q = $("#finder").val(); 
        var pattern = new RegExp( "^" + q, "i");

        $("#results").children().each(function(child){
            var label = $(this).find(".result-song-artist p").html(); 
            if (pattern.test(label)){
                $(this).show();
            }else{
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });  
    });
});
```

Comment: I am certainly going to implement your suggestion regarding the creation of a div id tag containing the index value.

Comment: With regards to rendering all the results and then showing them as is required, does the performance benefit of not redrawing the html on each filter change still remain when there are say 200 songs (objects)?

Comment: Yes.  Assume there are 200 songs.  With your approach, all of the HTML required to make those 200 divs will be recreated on every new letter of the filter.  With the approach I gave, the only computation done is searching through the 200 divs, compare regex, and hide/show.  There is no HTML generation in my approach other than on initialization.

Additionally, you can always test out my theory by appending 200 objects using a loop into multiArr.  Document runtimes as object count increases and graph it.  Never speculate on performance; write a proof of concept to ensure it WILL perform.

Comment: Unsurprisingly you are right :). I will the making the full amendments. However, I was wondering whether I wanted all the results to be showing until a search string is entered. Whether that was good UX design.

Comment: I couldn't get your appending part of your code to work for me though.